# How to handle google auth on android using Capacitor and passportjs?

Tags: google-oauth, passport.js, capacitor

I have created a web application using a Google Auth button on the frontend and Passportjs on an Express server.
I am trying to enable Google auth on Android, using Capacitor and `@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth`.
I manage to login the user in the browser : I receive the token and user data. However, I don't manage to authentify the user on the backend server.

I tried to send a request to the backend with the accessToken.
However, I get a CORS error and I don't understand why the server tries to reach google again.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?...' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/authenticate') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Frontend

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { GoogleAuth } = Plugins;

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    const googleUser = await GoogleAuth.signIn();
    const accessToken = googleUser.authentication.accessToken;

    // Now send the accessToken to your backend server
    sendAccessTokenToServer(accessToken);
};

const sendAccessTokenToServer = async (accessToken) => {
    // Make a request to your server to authenticate the user
    const response = await fetch('https://your-backend-server/authenticate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ accessToken }),
    });

    // Handle the response as needed
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
};
```

Backend

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

const app = express();

// Passport setup (assuming you are using Google OAuth)
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
    clientSecret: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    // Use the accessToken to authenticate the user
    // You might want to store the user in the session or your database
    // Return the user object to passport for serialization
    return done(null, profile);
}));

// Endpoint to handle the authentication request from the client
app.post('/authenticate', passport.authenticate('google-token'), (req, res) => {
    // If authentication is successful, send a response or redirect as needed
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Authentication successful' });
});
```